# Filter entities in spring repository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

It is possible to apply a filter to results with annotations instead of extending method name?

For instance:

```
@Repository
public interface JobRepository extends JpaRepository<Job, Long> {
    List<Job> findAllByUserAndEnabledIsTrue(User u);
}
```

Here I apply filter `'enabled == true'`. But assume we have a lot of methods. Writing them with extended names is inconvenient. Could I apply this filter to whole repository?

I found 
`@FilterDef` but I don't know how to use and also if spring support this annotation.

Comment: I do not think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Spring Data JPA is not Hibernate dependent, and it can work with any JPA implementation. Hibernate's `@Filters` is not a JPA standard, so the simple answer is no! Spring JPA does not support `@Filter`s.

But you can apply `@Filter`s using AOP, and simply applying aspects on your repository methods.

By the way I believe the better solution is to have hand written queries using Spring Data JPA's `@Query` annotation. Because this way you can name methods after their context meaning, and not about their internal implementation.

For example you can name your method `findActiveJobsForUser` which could be more meaningful and readable.

Comment: If you use Hibernate as your persistence provider (as most people do) there is nothing wrong or not working with using hibernate filters. JPA doesn't support it but that doesn't mean there isn't a way of using it (you even point that out in your answer).

Comment: I know that, but Spring Data JPA does not call `enableFilter()` and `disableFilter` methods on Hibernate Session. And when you use Spring Data you don't want to expose Hibernate Session to other tiers.

Comment: Even when using JPA you might (sporadicaly) want to use the underlying mechanism, because that mechanism can do more than JPA alone can. But as you state yourself you can use AOP to do that.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh Please, could you provide an example with AOP method? I can't imagine this. This AOP filter will work on a query (so the filter will be in the database) or on result of query?

Comment: In the AOP you must access the curren hibernate Session and enable the filter in it. I'll provide a sample soon